# Save Ghidra's control flow graph into a parsable format

Tags: ghidra, control-flow-graph

I'm working on reverse engineering a firmware which I was able to get its functions control flow graphs to display successfully on Ghidra. I am trying to see if there is a way to save those control flow graphs as a text file or something parse able so that I can write a parser for it and use it in my program (I want to recreate the graph programmatically to train my program to detect certain functions). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of trial and error I figured out something called GhidraDev which is an add-on to eclipse, through it you can create your own Ghidra projects and use the API with ease. Instructions on how to install it into eclipse can be found in ghidra_9.0.4 -> Extensions -> Eclipse -> GhidraDev -> GhidraDev_README.html.

Ghidra can be downloaded here: https://ghidra-sre.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [headless analyser] (https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/analyzeHeadlessREADME.html#recursive) script.

Check out it's usage [here](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/analyzeHeadlessREADME.html#usage). You can find this file in `ghidhra/support` directory.

The ghidra api is available [here](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/). You can use this api to write custom scripts, either in java or python 2.7.

Then you can do:

```
./analyzeHeadless /projectloacation projectname -import /binary_location -postscript /yourscript-location -deleteproject
```

To run your analysis. This command runs your script on binary by creating a new project and then deleting it later (`-deleteproject` flag, which is optional).

You can find a lot of examples in their [github repository](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/tree/49c2010b63b56c8f20845f3970fedd95d003b1e9/Ghidra/Framework). [e.g. script](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/49c2010b63b56c8f20845f3970fedd95d003b1e9/Ghidra/Features/Base/src/main/java/ghidra/app/plugin/core/analysis/ObjectiveC1_MessageAnalyzer.java).

As you said in your question, if you want to work with functions, you can:

```
functions = currentProgram.getFunctionManager().getFunctions(True)
```

get the list of functions (in python, changed the syntax if you are using java).

Comment: If I may ask, how do you import the API into eclipse or a development environment of the sort?

Comment: I am not sure about eclipse, because I used python. My take on this is - read the api, write a code in java, and then use the above command to run the code.

Comment: here is an example "hello world" script that you can run - https://github.com/DiegoMagdaIeno/Ghidra-Launcher/blob/ce4812955a020eed820af25796b5e9ff2b34e110/Ghidra/Features/Base/ghidra_scripts/HelloWorldScript.java